# Error: > while Migration @walletconnect/web3-provider => @walletconnect/ethereum-provider

Tags: typescript, next.js, provider, wallet-connect

```
   "@types/googlemaps": "3.39.3",
   "@types/markerclustererplus": "2.1.33",
   "@types/node": "^9.6.61",
   "@types/react": "^16.9.34",
   "babel-plugin-relay": "^10.1.1",
   "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.12.0",
   "ember-cli-materialize": "^0.22.0",
   "expose-loader": "^1.0.3",
   "relay-compiler": "^10.1.0",
   "typescript": "^3.8.3"
 },

"react": "16.14.0",
"react-scripts": "3.4.1",
"web3": "^0.20.7",
```

I faced dependecy error like webpack error, module not found error and some time type error due to typescript version change

Firstly i changed version of typescript to latest and react script to latest due to webpack not installed in package install it too.

typescript 5.1.6 , react script 5.0.1, working properly but while installing ethereum provider it showing error and then tried to change nextjs version to 10.2.3 same result.

Here is next.config.js file:

here is next.config.js

```
const withImages = require("next-images");
const withVideos = require("next-videos");

module.exports = withVideos(
  withImages({
    fileExtensions: ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif","svg"],
    env: {
    },
    webpack(config, { isServer }) {
      if (!isServer) {
        config.resolve.alias["@sentry/node"] = "@sentry/browser";
      }
      // Fixes npm packages that depend on `fs` module
      if (!isServer) {
        config.resolve.fallback.fs = false;
      }
      return config;
    },
    pageExtensions: ['.tsx', '.jsx', '.js']
  })
);
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.